# Radial gradient away from origin

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm trying to give a specific thickness profile to a 3D surface with cylindrical shape. My goal is to have a structure with a constant thickness up to a certain point from the center, which then increases significantly, and becomes constant again. It's important that the change in thickness is gradual so I can't simply cut 2 different objects and put them together. I can apply a radial thickness gradient using weight paint and solidify, but only in a circle, not in a ring shape, and the gradient is too abrupt (from 0.5 to 2 mm over a short distance) and too far from the center for me to just slap 3 objects together, 2 with constant thickness plus one with the gradient. Does anyone know of a way this can be achieved using blender, or any other software for that matter? I should mention that I'm new to Blender, i started using it for this specific purpose. Thank you[image]

Comment: Do you mean something like this? https://imgur.com/E7DZn39 Can you draw a profile (like cut in a middle and show side cut)

Comment: The trick with my model is that i'm working with a mathematically generated surface. I generate it via an equation in matlab, then I put it in an .stl format, and i send it to blender. 
So what i have is a porous cylinder essentially.
What I want to do now is give the porous cylinders walls a thickness gradient in that middle area shown in the picture. I hope I'm being clear in my explanation

Comment: Sorry if no one here ... Please share your blend via https://blend-exchange.com/ given code copy&paste into your question